# Is it possible to abbreviate URLs in RDF/XML attribute values?

Tags: xml, url, rdf, rdf-xml

I [found](https://metadatablog.blogspot.de/2012/03/introducing-metadata.html) the following XML snippet:

```xml
<structMap xmlns:np="urn:library-of-congress:ndnp:mets:newspaper">
    <div TYPE="np:issue" DMDID="issueModsBib">
```

In short: **Does `np:issue` resolve to `urn:library-of-congress:ndnp:mets:newspaper:issue`, or not?**

More formally: Does the above XML, converted to some kind of triple representation, contain the triple (let `$` be referencing the anonymous node representing the `<div>` element)

```
〈$, http://www.loc.gov/METS/TYPE, urn:library-of-congress:ndnp:mets:newspaper:issue〉
```

or does it contain the triple

```
〈$, http://www.loc.gov/METS/TYPE, "np:issue"〉
```

with `"np:issue"` being a plain literal?

I believe to remember that URLs in XML attribute values *cannot* be abbreviated using namespaces, but it was years ago I learned that. I read about [the proposal](https://www.w3.org/1999/03/31-XMLNamespace-values) to use `:=` assignment syntax (would be `<div TYPE:="np:issue">`) to tell the parser that the value is abbreviated by a namespace, but that (afaik) never made it to a standard. Maybe there is some new convention or even spec that I am not aware of? Or does the above, from a mechanically-semantically point of view, just not express what I believe it was intended to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they can't be abbreviated using namespace prefixes. The most that can be done is to use relative URIs in attributes and set an xml:base. See the [RDF 1.1 XML Syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax-grammar/#section-Syntax-ID-xml-base) specification for more details.